# Как определить, является ли матрица симметричной относительно главной диагонали?

Tags: python, массивы, матрицы

Есть целая квадратная матрица. Требуется определить является ли эта матрица симметричной относительно главной диагонали.

Мой код:

```
import random
n=int(input('Введите кол-во строк и столбцов матрицы: '))
h=('')
matrix=[[random.randrange(10) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
for elem in matrix:
    print(elem)
for k in range(n):
    for l in range(1,n):
        if matrix[k][l]!=matrix[l][k]:
            h=('False')
            break
if h!=('False'):
    print('Матрица симметрична')
else:
    print('Обычная матрица')
```

Все ли правильно я сделал? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for k in range(0,n-1):
    for l in range(k+1,n):
```